# How do I add a new row at the top of an existing pandas dataframe with a date field?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add a new row at the top of an existing pandas dataframe, I have tried to concatenate a new dataframe with an existing dataframe however this causes the rest of each row's dates to be cleared. (Showing NaN) - see [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKgEa.png), can anyone help on what I am doing wrong? I have been stumped for the past few hours.

```
import pandas as pd
loro = pd.read_csv('path to csv file', delimiter=';')
```

```
loro['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(loro['DATE'])
cols = ['N1','N2','N3','N4','N5','E1','E2']
loro.set_index('DATE',inplace=True)
loto = loro[cols].copy()
loto.head()
```

This outputs

```
N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  E1  E2
DATE                            
2023-10-17  10  17  20  35  40  3   4
2023-10-13  21  26  28  40  41  2   4
2023-10-10  18  20  22  33  43  3   9
2023-10-06  21  29  31  34  43  2   9
2023-10-03  6   20  22  24  45  4   5
```

I created a new dataframe and tried to concatenate this with an existing dataframe

```
new_row = pd.DataFrame({'DATE':'2023-10-20'}, index =[0])

loto = pd.concat([new_row, loto]).reset_index(drop = True)
loto.head(5)
```

This outputs

```
    DATE    N1  N2  N3  N4  N5  E1  E2
0   2023-10-20  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN 10.0    17.0    20.0    35.0    40.0    3.0 4.0
2   NaN 21.0    26.0    28.0    40.0    41.0    2.0 4.0
3   NaN 18.0    20.0    22.0    33.0    43.0    3.0 9.0
4   NaN 21.0    29.0    31.0    34.0    43.0    2.0 9.0
```

I am expecting a new row to be added without affecting the remaining rows' dates.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464), descriptions and images are accepted as a sole source of data.

Comment: Apologies. I have added a screenshot now in my post.

Comment: I explicitly mentioned in my comment that an image is **not** acceptable, please read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464) carefully and provide **code** to set up an example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to add an empty row, you need to craft `new_df` to have the DATE as **index** and `loto`'s columns:

```
new_row = pd.DataFrame(index=['2023-10-20'],
                       columns=loto.columns).rename_axis('DATE')
loto = pd.concat([new_row, loto])
```

Alternatively, using your original approach, first [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), then [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
new_row = pd.DataFrame({'DATE':'2023-10-20'}, index=[0])
loto = pd.concat([new_row, loto.reset_index()]).set_index('DATE')
```

Output:

```
              N1    N2    N3    N4    N5   E1   E2
DATE                                              
2023-10-20   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
2023-10-17  10.0  17.0  20.0  35.0  40.0  3.0  4.0
2023-10-13  21.0  26.0  28.0  40.0  41.0  2.0  4.0
2023-10-10  18.0  20.0  22.0  33.0  43.0  3.0  9.0
2023-10-06  21.0  29.0  31.0  34.0  43.0  2.0  9.0
2023-10-03   6.0  20.0  22.0  24.0  45.0  4.0  5.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! - Yes I was wanting to add an empty row. I experimented with both approaches and both seem to add in the time in the format of '00:00:00' to all the rows except the first row. (the empty row I added) How would I be able to strip the time from the dates?

```
 N1 N2 N3 N4 N5 E1 E2
DATE       
2023-10-20 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2023-10-17 00:00:00 10.0 17.0 20.0 35.0 40.0 3.0 4.0
2023-10-13 00:00:00 21.0 26.0 28.0 40.0 41.0 2.0 4.0
2023-10-10 00:00:00 18.0 20.0 22.0 33.0 43.0 3.0 9.0
2023-10-06 00:00:00 21.0 29.0 31.0 34.0 43.0 2.0 9.0
```

Comment: This is because you have strings/datetime64 try to use `pd.Timestamp('2023-10-20')` in place of `'2023-10-20'`.

Comment: Please update the question to add **code** for a reproducible input